# htaccess rewrite / redirect by getting the start of a string

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

I have a lot of old backlinks that worked on an old setup but not on wordpress. GA is showing the traffic is landing on things like:

```
https://www.example.com/404.html?page=/articles/3148-cats-dogs/gibberish.htm&stuff
```

I want to redirect these based on just the 4 digit number to a url like:

```
https://www.example.com/articles/3148
```

From here my site can find the correct post *eg. https:// [www.example.com/articles/3148-dogs-are-cool](http://www.example.com/articles/3148-dogs-are-cool)*

How do I do this?

.....

What I've managed so far is to catch a specific url and send it to the right place. But I can't figure out how to make it generic to any 4 digit number:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^\/404\.html$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^page=/articles/3148
RewriteRule .* https://www.example.com/articles/3148? [R=301,L]
```

I've been testing it over at https://htaccess.madewithlove.com?share=2026d0fc-b8e5-4f2a-9f37-7f8531142753

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I seem to have found a solution:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^\/404\.html$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^page=/articles?/(.{4})
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/articles/%1? [R=301,L]
```

From the help of @CBroe and @MrWhite below I've cleaned it up to:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^page=/articles/([0-9]{1,4})
RewriteRule ^404\.html$ https://www.example.com/articles/%1? [R=301,L]
```

Note: I realized some articles have less than 4 digits so `[0-9]{4}` has become `[0-9]{1,4}`

If anyone has more advice I'm all ears.

Comment: The `?` in the pattern would make the preceding `s` optional, so unless you also need to match URLs that contain the singular `article`, that can be removed. And `.{4}` matches _any_ four characters, if you want this to match digits only, it should rather be `[0-9]{4}`, or `\d{4}`. (But unless you actually had other URLs that would match the current pattern although the shouldn't, it probably doesn't make too much of a difference.)

Comment: And the first `RewriteCond` that matches against `REQUEST_URI` is not required. You should match the URL-path in the `RewriteRule` _pattern_ instead (which currently  matches everything and captures everything). So instead of `RewriteRule ^(.*)$`, it should be `RewriteRule ^404\.html$` and remove the first _condition_.